# Concept of true,false logically and numerically?

Tags: logic, boolean

I was asked this question in an interview! I just wanted to know what the right answer to this is. I told that logically the concept is represented by bool data type(C#).A variable of bool data type can have true or false value and can be used as a conditional check condition.Numerically, 1 represents true and 0 represents false in most programming languages.I don't know what else to add or what is the distinction between the two.Any comments will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't most languages' definition of `true` "anything except `0`"?

Comment: I can imagine that "Numerically, 1 represents true and 0 represents false in most programming languages." was not the answer the interviewer was looking for.

Comment: Looking at your question history, it appears that the replies you've received have answered your questions. Perhaps you should go and mark them as "accepted"?

Comment: Thanks, for the comments.I still don't get the difference though!

Answer (score 0):

In C# (unlike some other languages) booleans are not integers and are not convertible to integers:

```
int x = true; // Error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int'
```

As a result it doesn't make sense to say that true is equal to 1 in C#. At an implementation level the value true might be stored internally as the value 1, but this is a detail specific to that implementation, not a feature of C# itself.

If you want to convert a boolean to the value 0 or 1 you can do this:

```
int x = isFoo ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Does that mean that there is no concept of true and false numerically in C#?

Comment: Yes basically it is fair to say that there are no numerical values for true and false in C#.